# How to set failonerror=false on UNWAR task

Tags: ant

I have a target where multiple unwar tasks gets executed.
If an UNWAR task fail due to missing archieve file, i still want to execute other(next) UNWAr tasks in that target. How to do this.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

The third-party [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) has a [`<trycatch>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) that catches exceptions and then continues an Ant script:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />

<trycatch>
    <try>
        <unwar/> <!-- A fully configured unwar task here -->
    </try>
    <catch>
        <echo>The unwar task failed.</echo>
    </catch>
</trycatch>

<!-- The script continues here, even if the unwar task failed. -->
```